# Bind a JavaFx property to more than one observable

Tags: java, javafx, reactfx

I am writing a JavaFx control that consists of a sub-control that gets user input, e.g. a TextField. The main component holds a property which represents a parsed representation of the text, e.g. a LocalDateTime. When the user enters something, this property should be updated, so I bind it to the child's value property. It should also be possible to change the current value from outside via binding the value property, so this has to be a bidirectional binding to update the child automatically. The control works fine until client code binds to the property. The following code shows my problem:

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

```
public class Playbook {

    // The internal control with a property p
    static class Child {
        public SimpleIntegerProperty p = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public void set(int i) {p.set(i);}
    }

    // My new control with a property value which is bound
    // bidirectionally to Child.p
    static class Parent {
        public Child a1;

        public SimpleIntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Parent() {
            a1 = new Child();

            value.bindBidirectional(a1.p);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();

        // some client code wants to keep the 
        // value updated and thus binds to it
        SimpleIntegerProperty outside = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        p.value.bind(outside);

        // simulate a change in the child control
        p.a1.p.set(10);         
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get an exception that a bound property cannot be set:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalIntegerBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:467)
```

I am sure this must be a common  problem and I am just not seeing the obvious solution. I am using ReactFx, so any solution with plain JavaFx or ReactFx would be welcome. The real code uses a `Var.mapBidirectional` to bind the Parent and Child properties internally.

What I want to achieve is the following:
1. If `outside`'s value changes, this should be propagated to p.value and then to p.a1.p
2. If p.a1.p changes, this should be propagated to p.value

From this I concluded that Parent.value and Parent.a1.p are always identical (plus some tranformation applied in the mapping) and this I use a bidrectional mapping. outside can change independently and can be different to value, so I use a unidirectional binding.

Comment: `p.value.bind(outside);` means that `p.value` will always have the same value as `value`. `p.value.bindBidirectional(p.a1.p)` means that `p.value` and `p.a1.p` will always have the same value. Clearly these rules cannot both be enforced at the same time - specifically if you explicitly set `p.a1.p` to a value different to `outside`. You are getting an exception because you are trying to simultaneously enforce contradictory rules. There is no solution; you may as well declare `int i;` and ask how you can make `i=0` and `i=10` at the same time.

Comment: @James_D I am not sure I can follow that reasoning. Parent.value and Child.p should always have the same value. But with `p.value.bind(outside)` (which is a unidirectional binding?), I think I am saying that "When `outside` changes then `p.value` will be changed to the same value. When `p.value` changes `outside` is not changed and thus can have different values." I try to visualize this as outside -> value <-> p.

Comment: That's not what binding means. `p.value.bind(outside)` means that `p.value` is *bound to* `outside`: i.e. `p.value` will always have the same value as `outside`.

Comment: It is unidirectional (i.e. asymmetric) in the sense that `outside` is independent, and can be changed (in which case `p.value` will be updated), but `p.value` is dependent, and *cannot be directly changed*.

Comment: So if `p.value` is bound to something, and then you bidirectionally bind `p.value` to something else (`p.a1.p` in your somewhat convoluted example), then `p.a1.p` is effectively bound too, and cannot be independently changed either.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/package-summary.html) says: *"All properties can be bound to `ObservableValue`s of the same type, which **means that the property will always contain the same value as the bound `ObservableValue`**."* (My emphasis.)

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I was just looking for that reference. So how does one use properties to compose controls without manual listeners? Clients could bind bidirectionally, but this is not enforced in the type system and seems to expose internals. I think that a case like mine is quite common. Is there an example somewhere in the docs?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You are explicitly trying to enforce contradictory rules. You need to start by defining logical rules that aren't inherently contradictory. (Also: what do you mean by "clients could bind bidirectionally, but this is not enforced in the type system"?)

Comment: @James_D I don't think it's contradictory per se, but the bindings semantics make it contradictory. I understand that from the doc now. But I am thinking of something like a TimeField with a LocalTime property which uses a TextField to show and enter times. The LocalTime property needs to be bound bidirectionally to the TextField's value property using something like mapBidirectional. Now, I have a client code that only wants to show changing times. I would just bind to the LocalTime property and expect that this works, but it doesn't. And I cannot see it from the type of the property.

Comment: @James_D In old-style obsers semantics, the LocalTime property observes outside and the TextField. The TextField observes the LocalTime property, and ourside observes nothing.

Comment: @James_D I meant that if I do outside.bind(p.value) I get an exception, but if I outside.bindBidirectional(p.value) it works. There is nothing in the signature of the method to get the property or in the type of the property that tells me this. I have to rely on documentation exposing implementation details. Looks like my design is not appropriate.

Comment: You're overcomplexifying this with the bidirectional binding. You can repeat this entire discussion with a control and one external property, and it would be identical. If you bind the text property of a text field to some external property, then you *cannot change that text field*, whether by editing it or by some convoluted setup you define using a bidirectional binding. So if you bind the text field's text property to something, then you should make the text field non-editable, and avoid calling `setText()` on it.

Comment: In your more complex set up, then the same thing applies. If you have two controls whose underlying properties are bidirectionally bound, then it is encumbent on anyone who binds one of those properties to something to ensure that both controls are non-editable and they avoid setting either property directly. You would presumably make this easier in a control combining two such controls by exposing a single data property and a single disable property (etc) from your custom control.

Comment: As for the API design, it's not an implementation detail, it's the functionality of the `bind` method. `bind` means, well, the value is "bound". Allowing a bound property to be changed would violate the *functionality* of what "bind" means. I think it's pretty clear from the normal meaning of the word that once something is bound, it can't be changed. YMMV.

Comment: @Jens I share your frustration that very little in JavaFX is enforced at the type level. It is full of leaking implementation details and as a result not very composable.

Comment: @TomasMikula I agree in general, but in this case I find it hard to see how you would accomplish this at a type level. The issue is that a bound property should not be writable - however whether or not a property is bound is surely necessarily mutable, and so writability with respect to boundedness can't be enforced at compile time. Just out of curiosity, I'd be interested to see how you could make a better API for that.

Comment: @James_D I find it hard as well. But the contract of `WritableValue` is that it is, well, writable. All subtypes should respect that contract, but `Property` obviously doesn't. For what could have realistically been done in JavaFX, I will leave it at that. I could speculate how to ensure a _single_ writer at _compile_ time in principle, but that would go beyond what's practical/possible in Java and totally "non-JavaFX".

Comment: @James_D The idea would be that we write _immutable descriptions_ of components. When a property of a component is bound, we get a new description of the component (with a different type) where that property is no longer writable (has different type). The description of the whole application will in the end be interpreted by the platform. Binding to the same property on the same description multiple times would yield multiple descriptions, but ultimately only one description will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding that JavaFx Bindings are not what I thought it would be and that the semantics do not allow this, I switched to [ReactFx's](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) `EventStream/Val/Var`. ReactFx's model seems to be a better match to my expectation which allows me to create a system that behaves as follows:

1. If outside's value changes, this should be propagated to p.value and then to p.a1.p
2. If p.a1.p changes, this should be propagated to p.value

The following code implements this. It uses two `Var`s which are bound bidrectionally and thus changes in one of them are fed to the other `Var`. Changes from outside are defined as an `EventStream` which is fed to one of the `Var`s.

```
import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.EventStreams;
import org.reactfx.value.Var;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class Playbook {

    static class Child {
        public Var<Integer> p = Var.newSimpleVar(0);

        public void set(int i) {this.p.setValue(i);}
    }

    static class Parent {
        public Child a1;

        public Var<Integer> value = Var.newSimpleVar(0);

        public Parent() {
            this.a1 = new Child();

            this.value.bindBidirectional(this.a1.p);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();

        // some client code wants to keep the
        // value updated and thus binds to it
        SimpleIntegerProperty outside = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        // A SimpleIntegerProperty is not a Property<Integer> but a 
        // Property<Number> so we have to use map to translate to Integer
        EventStream<Integer> stream = EventStreams.valuesOf(outside).map(Number::intValue);

        stream.feedTo(p.value);

        // simulate a change in the child control
        p.a1.p.setValue(10);
        System.out.println( p.value.getValue() );
        System.out.println(p.a1.p.getValue() );
        System.out.println(outside.get());

        // feed new value from outside
        outside.set(42);

        System.out.println( p.value.getValue() );
        System.out.println(p.a1.p.getValue() );
        System.out.println(outside.get());
    }
}
```

The program runs and prints

```
10
10
0
42
42
42
```